# Starting Issue Question

Tags: starting, chevrolet, silverado

2009 Silverado with new ignition switch. Put in new switch because I thought that was the problem.When I turn the key the headlights, the radio and entire dash lights up but not a sound from the engine, not even clicks. From 3 more turns of the key to a few minutes the engine will eventually turn over. Occasionally there are clicks but very rarely.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the ignition switch. There's the part you replaced which is the key cylinder. The 2nd part is the ignition starter switch. The key cylinder recognizes the key and allows you to activate the starter switch. The starter switch is the electrical part which activates the starter. Since the starter itself is *sometimes* working, I'd venture to assume it is the starter switch which is bad. You can bench test your starter by removing it and applying power directly, or by taking it to an auto parts store. Most will test it for free.

Below is an image of the starter switch.

[image]

Comment: The picture you sent me is the part I replaced. Went out to start my truck this morning and it did the same thing except no clicking at all. Went out a few minutes later and it started on the second try?

Comment: You could have gotten a faulty one. Was this the same behavior before you swapped the part?

Comment: Yes. Someone said to me today it is possible my ground strap could be bad or my starter ground. Is this possible? This was the issue I was having before I put the new one in.

Comment: By the way, I did change the cylinder as well as the ignition switch.